# Por qué este Hola mundo no muestra resultado?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Estoy realizando un simple "hello World" me ejecuta sin errores pero no muestra nada en pantalla estoy utilizando IntelliJ

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello world")
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues estuve viendo video tutoriales y en kotlin funciona así y estoy haciendo exactamente lo mismo no se si sea un problema conel IDE

Comment: Pues en efecto [así se escribe el hola mundo](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/hello-world.html)... pero, creaste tu proyecto como indica [la documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/jvm-get-started.html)?

Comment: Según la documentación tu archivo debería ser `.kt` agrega la versión de kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que creaste un proyecto Android, aquí el "punto de inicio de tu aplicación" se encuentra en el método `onCreate()` de la Activity definida como "LAUNCHER" dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` , aquí es donde podrías definir la impresión del texto.

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


       println("Hello world")

  }
```

o como lo estas realizando, definir la clase y llamar la función `main()` que imprimiría el texto:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       main()

  }
```

---

Si deseas crear una aplicación Kotlin te sugiero instalar [Intellij IDEA](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/jvm-get-started.html) como lo realizaste y crear tu aplicación de esta forma definiendo `Application` o `Console Application`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También te sugiero usar el [playground de Kotlin](https://play.kotlinlang.org/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias si fue esto !

Comment: Excelente Julian!, saludos.